# Can `VirtualAllocEx` allocate more than one page?

Tags: c++, winapi

Does anyone know if the function [`VirtualAllocEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API could allocate more than one page when called?

For example, I want to allocate 100MB. I call the function. Can the memory allocated span several pages (for one call) or does it always allocate only one page of the exact size?

I performed some tests and it seems it allocates only one page of the exact size. I ask the question here because the following text on MSDN confuses me:

> Each page has an associated page state. The `VirtualAllocEx` function
> can perform the following operations:
>
> - Commit **a region of reserved pages**
> - Reserve **a region of free pages**
> - Simultaneously reserve and commit a **region of free pages**

So, does MSDN speak of allocating memory in general with this function (meaning we can allocate several pages by several calls) or it can allocate several pages in one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *page* always has a fixed size (say, 4Kb). If you allocate 16Kb, you allocate 4 pages, even if they are allocated as a single block.

If you mean to ask whether `VirtualAllocEx` can allocate several distinct *blocks of memory* then no, judging from that it returns just one pointer, it cannot. It returns one block of memory of the size you requested or larger.

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up between _memory page_ and _memory region_ (range of pages). I thought the reservation of made by VirtualAllocEx and the output of VirtualQueryEx directly return _memory pages_ but return _memory region_.

Answer (score 1):

`VirtualAllocEx` will allocate as many pages as it needs. A page has a fixed size measured in KB so if you allocate 100MB, it will certainly allocate many pages. I think that when you say page you mean something different.